# Como copiar dados de uma coluna para outra coluna da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Olá, boa tarde.

Tenho uma coluna tabela chamada City onde dentro dela tem 5 campos(CodeCompleto(PK), Code, Name, State, NameClear).

Essa NameClear foi criada para receber o Name sem acentuações.

Criei uma FUNCTION que retira essa acentuação e quando dou o select na dbo.city.name ele trás em ordem alfabética.

O que quero fazer é popular essa coluna NameClear com o resultado da pesquisa da FUNCTION... seria possível?

Comment: Já tentou `UPDATE City SET NameClear = function(Name)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer com que a coluna `NameClear` contenha o mesmo conteúdo da coluna `Name`, mas sem a acentuação, é declará-la como coluna calculada. Algo assim:

```
NameClear as dbo.SemAcento (Name)
```

Há vantagens e desvantagens nessa abordagem.

---

Outra opção é criar gatilho na tabela `City` que sempre que o conteúdo da coluna `Name` for alterado o mesmo ocorra na coluna `NameClear`, ao aplicar a função que retira a acentuação.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.retira_acento_Name
     on dbo.City
     after INSERT, UPDATE
as
begin
declare @NI integer, @ND integer;
set @NI= (SELECT count(*) from (SELECT top (2) * from INSERTED) as I);
set @ND= (SELECT count(*) from (SELECT top (2) * from DELETED) as D);

IF @NI > 0 and @ND = 0 
  -- trata inclusao
  begin 
  UPDATE C
    set NameClear= dbo.SemAcento (I.Name)
    from INSERTED as I
         inner join dbo.City as C on C.CodeCompleto = I.CodeCompleto;
  end

else
IF @NI > 0 and @ND > 0
  -- trata alteração
  begin
  IF UPDATE (Name)
    begin
    UPDATE C
      set NameClear= dbo.SemAcento (I.Name)
      from INSERTED as I
           inner join DELETED as D on D.CodeCompleto = I.CodeCompleto 
           inner join dbo.City as C on C.CodeCompleto = D.CodeCompleto
      where I.Name <> D.Name;
    end;
  end;
end;
go
```

Não testei; espero que não tenha erro(s).

---

A respeito de retirar acentuação, sugiro a leitura do artigo “[Retirar acentuação e caracteres “invisíveis](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/01/13/retirando-acentuacao-translate/)” que contém soluções interessantes sobre o assunto.